# NUnit tests for testing class-level PrincipalPermissionAttribute demands

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, security, nunit

I'm working with .NET 3.5 and Nunit 2.5.10. I'm attempting to write some tests to validate our role-based security enforcement through the `PrincipalPermissionAttribute` at a class-level.  The test appears to succeed (it gets a green checkmark) and the `Assert.Throws` call properly catches the exception, and all my other assertions about the exception pass.  However, once TearDown is complete after a test has run, the exception is re-thrown by NUnit.  So even though the test "passed", every one of the tests shows that an exception was unhandled exception was thrown 'while executing' the test run.

I'm guessing I'm doing something wrong, but can't figure it out.  My test is:

```
Public Sub New_TheForm_NoRoles_DeniesAccess()
    ' attempt to create a new instance of the form, but it should throw an exception with an inner SecurityException
    Dim ex As TypeInitializationException = Assert.Throws(Of TypeInitializationException)( _Function() New TheForm(), "Only admins and editors should have access.")
    Assert.That(ex.InnerException, [Is].TypeOf(GetType(SecurityException)), "Initialization should fail because of a SecurityException.")
End Sub
```

The form has PrincipalPermission attributes at the class level, like so:

```
<PrincipalPermission(SecurityAction.Demand, Role:=Security.Roles.ADMINISTRATORS)> _
<PrincipalPermission(SecurityAction.Demand, Role:=Security.Roles.EDITORS)> _
Public Class TheForm

' ... more class code here ...

End Class
```

Along with other checks to not even present options to the user, we're attempting to simply deny access to a given form based on the role received.  The role constants are tied to domain security groups, and I know they work (they are allowing / denying correctly when the application is run).

Early in the application, we *do* initialize our principal policy with a call to `UserSecurity.Initialize(Nothing)`.  The singleton UserSecurity's Initialize method is here:

```
Public Shared Sub Initialize(ByRef principalToUse As IPrincipal)
    ' if we don't have a principal, then use the windows principal
    If (principalToUse Is Nothing) Then
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetPrincipalPolicy(PrincipalPolicy.WindowsPrincipal)

    ' otherwise, use the principal passed in
    Else
        Thread.CurrentPrincipal = principalToUse
    End If
End Sub
```

Basically, Initialize is normally called in the application with `Nothing` so that we use the Windows Principal.  During unit testing, we instead initialize it with a GenericPrincipal that has no roles, so that we can test that a SecurityException is thrown.

The tests are passing, but NUnit just seems to be re-throwing the exception post-Teardown.  Any ideas what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your form finalizable, or are you perhaps disposing the form instance (for example, via a using statement) outside the context in which the "allowed" principal is set in the test?  In either case, you would end up trying to run a method (the finalizer or Dispose) under a user account that is not allowed to run any method in the form.  For a bit more detail and a workaround, see http://msmvps.com/blogs/calinoiu/archive/2006/01/07/why-is-my-application-coughing-up-a-securityexception-after-my-code-stops-running.aspx.

Comment: I actually found the answer, then came back and saw yours.  You are correct - specifically, the issue is because Dispose was being called, which was being denied.  I'll give you the answer, and detail a workaround in another one.

Answer (score 0):

As Nicole Calinoiu answered, it was caused by a later call to Dispose, *after the tests run*, resulting in a SecurityException.  The error from NUnit was misleading, saying it was 'during the test'.

The workaround, posted here for posterity, was to make sure to properly clean up the principal in the `TearDown` for the test fixture.  In this case, it meant making sure to reset the `Thread.CurrentPrincipal` to something with appropriate permissions, so that NUnit could then dispose of things, even after the test.